# Generics bypass constraints

Tags: swift, generics

This is my function:

```
func get<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type, subclass: T){}
```

I have an array of random objects. The objects that conform to the protocol Decodable should be able to call this function. This is what I mean:

```
class MasterClass{
    func get<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type, subclass: T){}
}

class A: MasterClass, Decodable{}

class B: MasterClass{}

func x(){
    let array: [MasterClass] = [A(), B()]
    for obj in array{
       if let conformer = obj as? Decodable{
           obj.get(type: type(of: conformer), subclass: conformer)
           //doesn't work
       }
   }
}
```

I do not get this to work, but I can not understand why.

> Cannot invoke 'get' with an argument list of type '(type:
>   Decodable.Type, subclass: Decodable)'

Comment: Protocols don't conform to themselves: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself - you need to pass a concrete type to `get`

Comment: @Cristik so it is not possible to say the to compiler that obj surely conforms to Decodable?

Comment: That's very possible, the method declaration is fine, the problem is how you call it: T needs to be a concrete type so that the compiler knows how to pass it to the called method

Comment: @Cristik How would I do that? I translated it to Java and I got an answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382457/call-generic-method-with-interface-constraints-on-objects-who-may-implement-that

Comment: It might not be possible with your current setup. What are you trying to achieve with this, maybe we can find another way