# Call generic method with interface constraints on objects who may implement that interface

Tags: java, generics

This is my code:

```
interface a {}
class b{}
class c extends b implements a{}
class d extends b{}
class e{
    public void makeItWork(){
        b[] bees = new b[] {new c(), new d()};
        for (b bee: bees){
            if (bee instanceof a) {
                a beeA = (a) bee;
                //how to call the method test if object bee conforms the the interface?
                test(beeA.getClass(), beeA);
                //this goes wrong
            }
        }
    }
    public <T extends a> void test(Class<T> classType, T concrete){
    }
}
```

Besides maybe the bad design, I would like to know if it is possible to call the method `test` on objects who implements the interface `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `test` method doesn't need a generic type parameter.

You can define it as:

```
public void test(Class<? extends a> classType, a concrete) {
}
```

P.S. please use capitalized class names.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get away without using generics at all here:

```
public void test(a concrete) {
}
```